# Accessing the DOM on child window on local system

Tags: javascript

Can anyone tell me why this only works when I upload it and not when I open it in a browser on my local system.

https://teac.lenguax.com/tests/ADP-Driver/ADP-001/testBed.html

The only difference I do see is that, when it is uploaded, I get https:// and when it is on my local system I get file:/// - is there any way I can make this work on my local system without having a local webserver?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Tyrone

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Three reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Answer (score 0):

> ...when it is on my local system I get file:/// - is there any way I can make this work on my local system without having a local webserver?

Security around the `file:` scheme is browser-specific. Chrome is fairly restrictive, whereas Firefox is more permissive. So you might try Firefox.

**But**: *Lots* of things are slightly different and off when you use content from the `file:` scheme rather than `http:`/`https:`. I **strongly** recommend using a local web server when doing browser programming. Any good IDE will have one built in, and there are many Node modules (for instance) that will run your project in a local server as well. (And installing a local server isn't all that difficult.)